# Windows 10 keeps opening the boot disk files instead of running ubuntu install disk

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, windows-10

Question is title, instead of running the boot disk, it ends up opening all of the files that were burned in the disk. How do I fix this.
(Trying to install current ubuntu / Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS )

Comment: How did you create the boot disk?  Did you burn a CD or is it a USB flash drive?

Comment: You are supposed to *boot* from the Ubuntu installation medium, not open it in Windows.

Comment: This is a Windows question and has nothing to do with Ubuntu other than the fact that the ISO does indeed have an autorun.ini Windows 10 will not autorun automatically it will only offer a "run" option as part of the discs menu. Beyond that you'd need to ask how to change windows default policy which is out of scope here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to BOOT into CD/DVD in order to install onto your hard disk. You CANNOT just open the CD/DVD in windows. Install the CD/DVD into your optical drive and reboot PC depending on what type PC you have, you need to go into your boot options and pick the boot from CD/DVD or boot from USB options. computer will then boot into LIVE MODE and you can choose to run in live mode or install straight to disk, you will have 2 choices.